# Is there a way to reduce or hide streaks on newly primed drywall before we paint?

Tags: painting, priming

We just finished priming our newly orange-peel textured walls with a drywall primer.  When it dried we noticed vertical streaks on the walls, about 6"-8" apart ~ we think they're paint roller demarcations. These streaks are only noticeable on walls that have a window reflecting light onto them. We can't sand the walls due to the orange peel texture, but we're wondering if a second coat of primer will make the streaks diminish some.  And will two topcoats of paint make the streaks disappear even more?

Comment: If roller marks additional paint will reduce the lines but one of the best / worst diy dry wall patch jobs I have seen was where they did an excellent job of tape and filling and sanding but then they masked off the area and shot it with orange peal they removed the tape and painted and the square outline where they masked it will be there forever. If roller lines more paint practice and a long nap roller will hide them.

Comment: By long nap roller do you mean a longer nap, such as 3/4"?  Our walls have a medium light orange peel and we used 1/2" nap (the 3/8" seemed a little short for us).  Unfortunately we don't have the luxury of more paint practice ~ wish we did.

Comment: The longer nap rollers will leave more paint but can make large lines, painters don’t use straight lines with a roller maybe watch some u tube videos to watch how to. I can describe by over lapping fan shape patterns never straight lines.